# Security Concerns: JWT + cookies for SPA

Tags: cookies, jwt

I'm reading about JWT, refresh tokens sessionIds and how to build a secure authentication with a SPA. From what I understood (assuming everything is HTTPS),

- Using only JWT (or refreshToken for that matter), stored in localStorage/sessionStorage: Vulnerable to XSS attacks.
- Using only sessionIDs (stateful server), stored in HTTPonly cookie: Vulnerable to CSRF attacks.
- Using JWT (stateless server) stored in HTTPonly cookie: Vulnerable to CSRF.

So my idea: Why not store short-lived JWTs in localStorage and sessionIDs in HTTPonly cookies? Are there any security issues with this scheme? I can't find a lot of info on the net of this practice, why is that?

Thanks.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand you. Do you want to use JWT + sessionID in the same SPA?

Comment: Yes, because only one is not secure enough in my opinion.

Comment: This does not make sense. Using a session with JWT means losing all its advantages: stateless and no database access in each request. You can be protected against XSS or CSRF using additional techniques

Comment: Could you present a technique with a stateless server which protects against XSS and CSRF?

Comment: Take a look here: https://auth0.com/blog/cookies-vs-tokens-definitive-guide/ Summarizing: You can store JWT in `localStorage` adding a protection against XSS sanitizing inputs and outputs (localStorage is not vulnerable to CSRF), or you can use JWT with `HTTPOnly-cookies`  adding a protection with a CSRF token sent and validated in each request. Most frameworks implement CSRF protection and sanitize input/output automatically. If your framework does not do it, look for a plugin

Comment: I generally use React or Angular as my framework, they do sanitizing. But what if I use one external component that does not? Seems like a risk to me. Unless there are meta-plugins which protect sanitizes inputs from all the plugins.

Comment: Another remark. If I store the JWT in `HTTPOnly` cookies, on the server-side, I need to store this CSRF token in the database; and on the client side I store it in the localStorage, is that correct?

Comment: Yes, it is a risk, so you need to select the right framework and tools to maintaing your app securized.

Comment: The CSRF token will be stored in server, and in client side it is not needed to persist it because it is only valid for the following request.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/150093/discussion-between-amaurymartiny-and-pedrofb).